# selenium clicking a href button

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler

I am really new to selenium.
Currently, I am trying to use both selenium and beautifulsoup to do some webcrawling. The website that I am webcrawling on is `https://bigd.big.ac.cn/dogsdv2/pages/modules/indsnp/indsnp_search.jsp`. 
this is the code that I have for now.

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path_to_chromebrowser)
driver.get("https://bigd.big.ac.cn/dogsdv2/pages/modules/indsnp/indsnp_search.jsp")
input_area = driver.find_element_by_name("searchForm.genename")
input_area.send_keys("P2RY12")
searcher = driver.find_element_by_class_name("button")
searcher.click()
# table = driver.find_element_by_class_name("table7 table7-border")
# table.find_element_by_tag_name("a").click()
```

I am trying to click the first SNP ID that comes up, upon search. What would be the good way for me to click the href of the search result?

Answer (score 2):

ON the webpage `https://bigd.big.ac.cn/dogsdv2/pages/modules/indsnp/indsnp_search.jsp` to search for the *Gene Name* as **P2RY12** and click the first *SNP ID* that comes up upon search you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')

  driver.get('https://bigd.big.ac.cn/dogsdv2/pages/modules/indsnp/indsnp_search.jsp')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#idgname[name='searchForm.genename']"))).send_keys("P2RY12")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.button[type='submit']").click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "form[action^='/dogsdv2/com/exportFile'] table>tbody>tr td:nth-child(3)>a"))).click()
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: dogsearch]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
firstsnpID = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(.//table[@class='table7 table7-border']/tbody/tr/td[3]/a)[1]")
firstsnpID.click()
```

you can not use compound classes to locate element using `find_element_by_class_name`

Answer (score 0):

To click on first link on the table induce `WebDriverWait`() and `element_to_be_clickable`() and following CSS selector.

**Code**:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path_to_chromebrowser)
driver.get("https://bigd.big.ac.cn/dogsdv2/pages/modules/indsnp/indsnp_search.jsp")
input_area = driver.find_element_by_name("searchForm.genename")
input_area.send_keys("P2RY12")
searcher = driver.find_element_by_class_name("button")
searcher.click()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"table.table7.table7-border td>a[href^='/dogsdv2/refsnp/showRefSNPDetail']"))).click()
```

---

To get all the link induce `WebDriverWait`() and `visibility_of_all_elements_located`() and get the href value then iterate each url

```
allelemets=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"table.table7.table7-border td>a[href^='/dogsdv2/refsnp/showRefSNPDetail']")))

allurls=[item.get_attribute('href') for item in allelemets]
print(allurls)
for link in allurls:
   driver.get(link)
```

Answer (score 0):

`driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/a[1]').click()`

If you need other ids:
`for id in range(1,10):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/table/tbody/tr[{}]/td[3]/a[1]'.format(id)).click()
    sleep(5)
    driver.back()`